# How to do a if else match on pattern in awk

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I've tried the below command:

```
awk '/search-pattern/ {print $1}'
```

How do I write the else part for the above command?

Answer (score 30):

[Classic way:](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#If-Statement)

```
awk '{if ($0 ~ /pattern/) {then_actions} else {else_actions}}' file
```

`$0` represents the whole input record.

[Another idiomatic way](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Conditional-Exp)
based on the ternary operator syntax `selector ? if-true-exp : if-false-exp`

```
awk '{print ($0 ~ /pattern/)?text_for_true:text_for_false}'
awk '{x == y ? a[i++] : b[i++]}'

awk '{print ($0 ~ /two/)?NR "yes":NR "No"}' <<<$'one two\nthree four\nfive six\nseven two'
1yes
2No
3No
4yes
```

Answer (score 22):

A straightforward method is,

```
/REGEX/ {action-if-matches...} 
! /REGEX/ {action-if-does-not-match}
```

Here's a simple example,

```
$ cat test.txt
123
456
$ awk '/123/{print "O",$0} !/123/{print "X",$0}' test.txt
O 123
X 456
```

Equivalent to the above, but without violating the [DRY principle](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjG5KqgkM7bAhWIBcAKHepUAFAQFggxMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FDon%2527t_repeat_yourself&usg=AOvVaw3ALV8DXava0KllhLYVVUYB):

```
awk '/123/{print "O",$0}{print "X",$0}' test.txt
```

This is functionally equivalent to `awk '/123/{print "O",$0} !/123/{print "X",$0}' test.txt`

Comment: @EdMorton what is then the best option? The `{print ($0 ~ /pattern/)?text_for_true:text_for_false}` approach in [George's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44754982/1983854)?

Comment: @fedorqui yes if the "else" part is also a print (which is also the 3rd option in my answer for that case). Otherwise the 1st or 2nd option in my answer.

Comment: The last suggestion (the one conforming to the DRY principle) should contain a 'next' like this:
awk '/123/{print "O",$0; next}{print "X",$0}'

Answer (score 19):

Depending what you want to do in the `else` part and other things about your script, choose between these options:

```
awk '/regexp/{print "true"; next} {print "false"}'

awk '{if (/regexp/) {print "true"} else {print "false"}}'

awk '{print (/regexp/ ? "true" : "false")}'
```

Answer (score 11):

The default action of `awk` is to print a line. You're encouraged to use more idiomatic awk

```
awk '/pattern/' filename
#prints all lines that contain the pattern.
awk '!/pattern/' filename
#prints all lines that do not contain the pattern.
# If you find if(condition){}else{} an overkill to use
awk '/pattern/{print "yes";next}{print "no"}' filename
# Same as if(pattern){print "yes"}else{print "no"}
```

Answer (score 3):

This command will check whether the values in the $1 $2 and $7-th column are greater than 1, 2, and 5.

!IF! the values do not mach they will be ignored by the filter we declared in awk.

(You can use logical Operators and = "&&"; or= "||".)

```
awk '($1 > 1) && ($2 > 1) && ($7 > 5)'
```

You can monitoring your system with the "vmstat 3" command, where "3" means a 3 second delay between the new values

```
vmstat 3 | awk '($1 > 1) && ($2 > 1) && ($7 > 5)'
```

I stressed my computer with 13GB copy between USB connected HardDisks, and scrolling youtube video in Chrome browser.

[image: vmstat filtered column values]

[image]