# Awk with an IF condition

Tags: awk

I have a file called: input:

```
160957 docliente_up hdfs://nameservice1/user/hive/warehouse/docliente_up.db
160958 docliente_bu hdfs://nameservice1/user/hive/warehouse/docliente_bu.db
```

I am using awk to compare $2 with words ending in up

```
awk '{ if ($2 = "*_up" ) 
print "UPDATE DBS SET DB_LOCATION_URI=\"hdfs://nameservice1/databases_users/" $2"\"" " WHERE DB_ID=\""$1"\";";
else 
print "UPDATE DBS SET DB_LOCATION_URI=\"hdfs://nameservice1/databases/" $2"\"" " WHERE DB_ID=\""$1"\";";}' input
```

but isn't work. I have been looking for a expresion to solve my problems but I can't find it.

Comment: Try `if ($2 ~ /_up$/ )` instead of `if ($2 = "*_up" )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '($2 ~ /_up$/){print "UPDATE DBS SET DB_LOCATION_URI=\"hdfs://nameservice1/databases_users/" $2"\"" " WHERE DB_ID=\""$1"\";"}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
UPDATE DBS SET DB_LOCATION_URI="hdfs://nameservice1/databases_users/docliente_up" WHERE DB_ID="160957";
```

Comment: Thank you. That it is exactly that I want.

Answer (score 0):

You must do the if in a block, and add curly brackets:

```
awk ' { if ($2 ~ /_up/) { print "YES ", $0 } else { print "NO ", $0 } }' /tmp/SO
```

Related question on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44754844/how-to-do-a-if-else-match-on-pattern-in-awk).